# Validate the JSON object availablity in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Inside the json object I traverse upto 4 level something any of the level may undefined and code break.

How validate/check json node in JavaScript not in jquery

```
productDetail.breadcrumb.levels.push(paramObj.categories.category.category.category.CATEGORYNAME);
```

Comment: All you can do is `try .. catch` - although generally you should know the structure of your data.

Comment: some time data structure may change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check it like this :

```
var categoryName = (paramObj.categories 
                    && paramObj.categories.category
                    && paramObj.categories.category.category
                    && paramObj.categories.category.category.CATEGORYNAME);
```

This will give you the category name or undefined if any of the objects along the way are not there.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract it out into a checking function

```
function myJsonValue(ob, prop) {
    var propsArray = prop.split('.');
    var out = ob;
    var i;
    for (i=0; i < propsArray.length; i += 1){
        var dis = propsArray[i];
        if (!out[dis]) {
            return undefined;
        }
        out = out[dis];

    }
    return out;
}
```

Usage:

```
myJsonValue(paramObj, "categories.category.category.category.CATEGORYNAME")
```

[(Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/chim/ZNTFm/3/)

Comment: For in is meant for iterating over object property lists.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript